# Salesforce Maintenance Page Issue

Tags: community

I have created a community and it working fine for me with this url:

https://sandbox-saleycommuni-developer-edition.cs114.force.com/test/

But when I am trying short this URL like this:

https://sandbox-saleycommuni-developer-edition.cs114.force.com
Then it is showing me standard maintenance page instead of my custom page.

[image]

I am completely unknown to this and could not find any  document about it.

Comment: Have you activated your site?  Can you check Customize->Communities->Manage Communities, check list of Visualforce pages enabled for community

Comment: Yes i have activated the site and error page assignment is also i checked

Comment: @vinay i want standards page to be replaced with my custom page. the standard maintenance vf page is overridden by my code. I just wanted know where from this page being displayed